# Connect to the raspberry over SSH via mobile connection

Tags: ethernet-port, port-forwarding, web-interface, ppp, modem

I finally got it working that I can use a Huawei E173 modem on my raspberry. When activating it with

> sudo ifup 3gModem

everything works fine, and it connects itself to my Server as I can see it in the log files. But when I try to connect to the modem IP via port 22 it won't work. Same with apache. I installed an apache server on it. And when i call the raspberrys IP over the wlan0 interface I can access is, with the ppp0 interface it completly blocks everything that goes into the pi. Not even pinging is possible. Do you know any solutions to this? I tried googling for sometime but nothing useful came up

Comment: Reverse SSH is the way! You would find a lot of issues trying to setup ssh through mobile network, reverse ssh will make it much simplier.

Comment: do you know any good tutorials for reverse ssh with windows and raspbian?

Comment: No sorry i. I'll draft up an answer with the basics of what you need to do, and from there you should be able to do the setup pretty easily with some more googling.

Comment: well I already did that but sorry for asking

Comment: well i guess no help must be better than some help for you.

Comment: Are you sure you modem connection does not go through NAT?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to enable SSH in raspi-config.  you can also try reinstalling openSSH-server with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openssh-server
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

you may also need to set up port forwarding on your gateway as well.  this would be a network configuration problem and not a RPi problem.

Comment: ssh is enabled, I reinstalled it and I don't quite have access to my gateway. I mean it's directly within the providers network. Do you think maybe reverse SSH or a VPN connection could help me solve this?

Comment: i think if you cannot configure the device to forward port 22 (or a port in general for SSH) you will never be able to get it to work with SSH.  I believe VPN still requires port forwarding in addition to some other IP protocols.

Comment: well it can't be impossible